# Save Video of 10seconds from a video file using Opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am able to save till i press escape, But want video of 10 seconds.
I am unaware of time related Libraries in c++. Thank you!

```
    while(true){
            Mat oneFrame;
            bool check=vid.read(oneFrame);
            if(!check){
                cout<<"something went wrong\n";
                cin.get();
                break;
            }
            vW.write(oneFrame);
            imshow(window_name, oneFrame);
            if(waitKey(10)==27){
                cout<<"Exiting because ESC is pressed\n";
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay So i just found a simple trick,
I know the frame rate, Using int x=vid.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
i.e  x frames are there in one second, So Use i in loop till x*10;